# Take a particular string from a file using php

Tags: php

Dear All,
i have a txt file like:

```
--start--
  jeff
--end--
--start--
  sophya
--end--
```

Now i need to collect the names like jeff and sophya into an array.How i do it?I use below code but its not give me proper output.

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/sample.txt');
$start_position = strstr($data,'--start--');
$end_position    = strpos($data,'--end--') ;
$value=substr($start_position,$end_position);
print_r($value);
exit();
```

My out put is : `--end-- --start-- sophya --end--`

is their any kind heart who help me to take two name into an array?
thanks in advance.riad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few approaches you can use here... I would personally use a regular expression to match what you need. [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://localhost/sample.txt');

preg_match_all('/--start--(.*?)--end--/ms', $contents, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $name) {
    var_dump($name);
}
```

**Note:** This includes the end of line characters on each side. To exclude them from the names, and and whitespace use the pattern `'/--start--\n\s*(.*?)\s*\n--end--/ms'`

I should mention, the advantage of this is it will automatically ignore things that are not in the correct format.

e.g. In the following file, `asd` will be ignored.

```
--start--
  jeff
--end--
asd
--start--
  sophya
--end--
```

Comment: Thanks..that's the solution that i m looking for. Thanks Jacob.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/sample.txt');
$data = str_replace('--end--', ' ', $data);  // remove existence of --end--
$data = explode('--start--', $data);  // resulted array
unset($data[0]);
echo implode(' ', $data);
```

Comment: +1, this is actualy faster than the two answers bellow isn't it ?

Comment: You would also need to remove the first blank element from the array. And it relies on well formed input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = '--start--
  jeff
--end--
--start--
  sophya
--end--';

preg_match_all('/--start--\n(.*)\n--end--/iu', $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

This asumes you allways have a new line after --start-- and before --end--